# How to jump to next element of the same type

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="story">
<p>lorem ipsum...</p> // for example this is clicked
<textarea></textarea>
<p>lorem ipsum...</p> // need to select
<textarea></textarea>
<p>lorem ipsum...</p>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

js

```
$("#story > p").click(function() {
var a = $(this).next("p").html();
});
```

Clicking on a paragraph I need to select next paragraph and not the next element (textarea in this case).

Comment: Use `.nextAll('p').first()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` searches for only immediate next element. Use `nextAll` instead like below.

```
$("#story > p").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).nextAll("p:first").html();
});
```

Comment: how it is different from what Josh posted ?

Comment: Actually these two are same (`:first` introduced  around since `jquery 1.0` and `first()` introduced  since `jquery 1.4` ). Josh posted when I was typing. @DinoMyte